# Object Tracking in hololens

Tags: opencv, hololens

Does anyone work on object detection/tracking on Hololens? I'm expecting to automatically detect a physical object using a marker or without a marker.

As per my knowledge we have a library like OpenCV based on raw images. But, HoloLens is a powerful computer vision device. Is there a possibility Microsoft might expose some high-level object detection API?

Comment: Natively speaking, AR devices are limited due to the amount of processing power it takes to perform most of these requests. The software is there as you can see with things such as OpenCV. However, the hardware just isn't there yet when it comes to native support for something like full blown marker less object detection. Right now, there is no native "hidden api" intelligence that would be able to distinguish one mesh blob for another. It only knows that "hey there's a blob over there and lets add it to all the other blobs we have so far."

Comment: Microsoft provides an (experimental) HoloLens/OpenCV package over here: https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLensForCV - Apparently it allows you to retrieve the raw sensor data and to process it on a dedicated host.

Answer (score 3):

With the actual version of Hololens it not could be done native. [Rumors](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/24/16018558/microsoft-ai-coprocessor-hololens-hpu) says that the next version will come with a IA chipset for this porpoise. 
In the meanwhile, you can use thinks like [Vuforia Object Detection](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Training/Object-Recognition.html) which works smoothly.

Anyway, there is a version of the OpenCV in the [Unity Asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088) store which come with severals samples of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Recently i come across SDK of vision lib which does this stuff very well.

Comment: Great. Can you provide any link to that SDK?